# Remove empty <ul> nodes from IXMLDOMDOCUMENT in Delphi

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2007

I have many xml nodes in an xmldocument. I want to remove all the empty `<ul>` nodes. How can I accomplish this?

Here is a snippet:

```
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Level 1</a>
    <ul id="subject19">
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Level 2</a>
        <ul id="subject20">
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Level 3</a>
            <ul id="subject21"/>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

I need to remove `<ul id="subject21"/>`

Comment: Which XML library are you using?

Comment: Use `RemoveChild` on the parent node

Comment: I need to recursively loop through the structure, identify the empty nodes and remove. I'm not sure how to accomplish this. I am aware of RemoveChild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple recursion. Here is an example how:

```
procedure ScanAndRemove(aNode: IXMLNode);
var
  i: Integer;
  childNode: IXMLNode;
begin
  i := 0;
  while i < aNode.ChildNodes.Count do
  begin
    childNode := aNode.ChildNodes[i];
    if (childNode.NodeName = 'ul') and (childNode.ChildNodes.Count = 0) then
      aNode.ChildNodes.Remove(childNode) else
      begin
        ScanAndRemove(childNode);
        Inc(i);
      end;
  end;
end;
```

And just pass the document root element:

```
procedure Cleanup;
var
  xmlDoc: IXMLDocument;
begin
  xmlDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  try
    xmlDoc.LoadFromXML('...');
    ScanAndRemove(xmlDoc.DocumentElement);
    // now xmlDoc contains the desired result
  finally
    xmlDoc := nil;
  end;
end;
```

**EDIT** 
The recursive function **will** remove a node without children, but containing a value. Eg:

```
<ul>
  blabla
</ul>
```

If you want the opposite, you should add one more check - ie:

```
if (childNode.NodeName = 'ul') and 
  (childNode.ChildNodes.Count = 0) and 
  (VarToStrDef(childNode.NodeValue, '') = '') then
  ...
```

Or this way - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9673869/3962893